# forex_python.converter CurrencyRates Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

Tags: python, django, api

I use forex python CurrencyRates in many of my project, but now it doesn't work, none of them.
Is there any problem with my code or are the server down? or what happend?

Here is my Code:

```
from forex_python.converter import CurrencyRates

c = CurrencyRates()
usd = c.get_rate('EUR', 'USD')
```

And the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\MeineDaten\Programmieren\Python\Projekte\Flask\ProjectX\main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from files.currency import currency
  File "D:\MeineDaten\Programmieren\Python\Projekte\Flask\ProjectX\files\currency.py", line 7, in <module>
    usd = c.get_rate('EUR', 'USD')
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\forex_python\converter.py", line 66, in get_rate
    response = requests.get(source_url, params=payload)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.ratesapi.io', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/latest?base=EUR&symbols=USD&rtype=fpy (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001F0C1D056A0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[www.ratesapi.io/](http://www.ratesapi.io/) now redirects to https://exchangeratesapi.io/pricing/. Looks like they're moving away from a wholly free API. Not sure what the future of forex-python will be if the underlying source becomes a paid service

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the api that the package uses is broken, I am having the same issue. Also if you go to https://api.ratesapi.io the website doesn't load.

Comment: This seems like a "me too" response rather than an answer to the question posed above.